# Returning from activity B->A via Android HOME button does not restore intent

Tags: java, android

I have activity A that gets passed a long ID value via long extra, when the activity is initially launched. When I go from A-B, and then press home, the ID value is gone. How can I restore it?

When going from A->B

```
Intent intent = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I've tried:

- Using bundle in `onSaveInstanceState`, `onRestoreInstanceState`
- Getting the ID from `getIntent` in `onResume`
- Getting the ID from `getIntent` in `onCreate`
- Getting the ID from saved bundle in `onCreate` (it's always null,
  even when `onSaveInstanceState` is called)
- Overriding `onFinish` in activity B Explicitly handling
  `android.R.id.home` case in `onOptionsItemSelected` in Activity B

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is `onFinish` in your code?

try this code in your B Activity to get it finish when you press up button in actionbar

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // Respond to the action bar's Up/Home button
    case android.R.id.home:
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Comment: 4 days of banging my head against a wall...thank you sir. I think `return true` instead of `break` was the difference